# can spring-managed-transaction survives multiple request-response-s?

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

im currently developing using jsf 2, jpa 2, and spring 3.

I think i quite understand the use of @Transactional and it's propagation, but stil, that only applies to one thread, which in my case is one request response of my webapp

Basically what i need is :

1. the client of the remote business service is the one that initiates and ends the transaction
2. spring wil do the exception translation if any exception occurs

Here's an example that hopefully can describe the intention :

1. the client(assuming it's a mobile device, not necessarily a webapp) ask the server to create a new transaction
2. the server returns a transaction id
3. the client calls serviceA, passing the transactionId to use
4. the serviceA runs using the transaction (based on the transactionId passed) finishes, but the transaction is not commited
5. the client continues calling serviceB, passing the same transactionId to use
6. serviceB runs using the previous transaction initiated by serviceA
7. if serviceB runs correctly, then the client can ask the server to commit based on the transactionId
8. if serviceB runs with exception, spring could then do the sql exception translation

Is this possible ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I hope you actually don't *need* such a long transaction... It usually is quite a bad idea, since transactions should be as short as possible (just [google this mantra](http://www.google.com/search?q=transactions%20as%20short%20as%20possible) for explanations if you doubt it).

Instead, it may be possible that you just need "long conversations": basically, you work with detached entities across multiple calls/requests (making read-only accesses to your database), then you reattach them (with your changes) when you're ready to commit your tx.

Either way, @Transactional is indeed of no use here and I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box mechanism achieving what you describe.

Maybe consider using spring webflow: it provides easy-to-use conversation-related features and should work very well in your context (JPA/JSF)...

See related discussion [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?41719-declarative-tx-for-unit-of-work).

HTH